# How to get commissions owed if contract was breached by owner

Tags: ethics, project-management, contractors, business, family-business

My firm was contracted to open a used car dealership.  Took me 5 months to open the dealership due to previous owner being non-compliant within the City.  Owner was impressed, as others had tried to open his dealership with win. He asked me to stay on he will pay me a base income along with 20% on every sale.  He noted for the commission I should give him 3 months to build up the business which I did.  It’s been 10 months and no commission.  He is now offering me a bonus.  I have made him $99,121.15 in 10 months. Should I quit or should I demand my money then quit?

Comment: Did you sign a contract stating that you would be paid commission?

Comment: Yes, however because he asked me to wait verbally  does that void my contract?

Comment: I don't think that a verbal request is enough to void a written contract but you probably need to seek legal counsel to be sure.

Comment: As this is b2b sort of deal I assume you have a solid contract that was reviewed by a lawyer and everything. So just follow up with said lawyer, and take it from there how to get your money.

Comment: Verbal contracts aren't invalid, they are just hard to prove. If he asked you to "wait" and you said "yes" then that is a real contract that supersedes the previous one you made. If he doesn't have proof then you can always deny you agreed, if you are OK with doing that. And of course that is a general statement - a real lawyer will tell you whether it applies to your specific case.

Comment: If you are able to build up a used car dealership in this short of time, I suggest that you seek out investors and build a competing dealership. That way, you get all the commission. The best revenge on being stiffed is to out compete and take away all his business.

Comment: Why did you wait an additional 7 months to ask about the commission? If your contract stipulates 20% of every sale, then not only are you owned month for sales during those first three months, you are owed sales for every month you have worked there.  Any bonus you might receive would be entirely separate from any commission you are owed.  Of course only you know the full details of the written contract.

Answer (score 6):

Neither - Go talk to a lawyer and do whatever they tell you. Make no statements about your plans to your boss or coworker before you talk to this lawyer. If your boss blew you off for 7 months, there is no making demands.

Comment: And find out how much the lawyer will cost. It might cost far more to hire a good lawyer than you will get if you win. Hiring a bad lawyer is just wasting more money.

Comment: True, though depending on your location and the exact circumstances of everything, it seems likely that OP would be able to also win lawyers fees in a settlement. Also something to discuss with the lawyer.